# How to access native Android services from a Gluon Mobile app?

Tags: android, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I'd like to call native services from my very basic Gluon Mobile application on an Android device. For example, by how it's done in the GoNative sample application, I can obtain a `TelephonyManager` instance like this:

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager= (TelephonyManager)FXActivity.getInstance().getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

But the example seems not to be up to date. I see that it uses earlier versions of several libs in die `build.gradle` file while in my config, the `3.0.0`versions are used.

It seems that there were API changes as `FXActivity` doesn't even offer the `getSystemService()` function anymore.

So, in the current version, how can I obtain a TelephonyManager and access the rest of the native Android services?

Comment: There hasn't been API changes, and `getSystemService()` is available. GoNative sample is up to the date, other than it uses a previous Charm version, so the procedure to get a `TelephonyManager` instance is exactly what you have described. Post any relevant code in case it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: @JoséPereda I agree with you. I see that when I try to set my project dependencies back to v2.1.1, the Interface of `FXActivity` doesn't change. But: In the GoNative sample I downloaded, the IDEA decompiler shows that `FXActivity`provides the method, in my Project, set up by the Gluon IDEA wizard, it doesn't. More irritating to me is that in both projects, `org.javafxports:jfxdvk` is of version 8.60.7. So I don't understand where the differences come from and I'd be glad for any idea or advice.

Comment: Have you checked out the GoNative sample from [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/master/GoNative/)? Have you seen the [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative)? It is a step by step guide showing how it can be created.